How to turn off scrolling for a numericInput?
Does anyone know how to turn off the slider feature of a numericInput in R Shiny?. When I run my app and am entering an input into the numeric input field, if the field is still selected and the user scrolls down, it changes what's entered into the input field. Is there a way to make it to where scrolling doesn't change the input field?
I tried using shinyjs but couldn't get it to work.

Please provide minimum reproducible example.

We can inject this JS solution to prevent scrolling for numericInputs:
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$script(HTML(
    "document.addEventListener('wheel', function(event){
        if(document.activeElement.type === 'number'){
            document.activeElement.blur();
        }
     });"
  )),
  numericInput("blur_on_scroll", "blur_on_scroll", 0L, 10L)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)

Please see this related article.

This is only applicable if the user scrolls with their mouse wheel - using the down arrow still has an effect.

@smartse scrolling is what OP asked for.

This may not be what you are after, but you can disable them entirely if you want (via geeksforgeeks):
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(
    'input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
     input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
                -webkit-appearance: none;
                margin: 0;
            }

            input[type="number"] {
                -moz-appearance: textfield;
            }'
  )),
  numericInput("a", "A", 0L, 10L)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)

